# Good free offline PL/SQL formatter

Tags: sql, plsql, formatting, offline

Is there a good formatter for PL/SQL which is free and offline?

Comment: Related: [Command line SQL formatter or beautifier - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85348/command-line-sql-formatter-or-beautifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a desktop version for [SQLinForm](https://www.sqlinform.com)

Comment: The desktop version is not working till March 09, but this kind of tool is what I was looking.

Thank you

Comment: The desktop version is working fine now

Answer (score 8):

I am not really sure what you mean by "offline". However, Oracle has a tool called SQL Developer that is free and can be downloaded from their website.  It has some formatting options you can apply to your code.

Comment: I mean that does not require an internet connection. I will try both sugestions. Thank both.

Comment: SQL Developer does not require an internet connection.

Comment: Can SQLDeveloper be configured so that output won't suck? For example, it insists on putting every column in SQL statements on its own row, and aligning := operators below each other, even if interspersed with other code...

Comment: Ditto to what Juraj said -- SQLDeveloper's formatter appears to be designed to format single SQL statements, not PL/SQL. It makes a hash of my packages, anyway.

Comment: Use CTRL-F7 to format your SQL in SQL Developer. Also you can completely customize the formatting in Tools > Preferences > Database > SQL Formatter > Oracle Formatting > Edit Profile

Answer (score -4):

[Instant SQL formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) is a free and online SQL formatter without any query size limitation.

Comment: Except OP specifically does not want an online tool. I'm in the same boat: I can't upload my work to a random server.